# Catalog url are going 404 after upgrading Magento 2.4.4

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2-enterprise, magento2-cloud, magento2.4.4, catalog-url-rewrite

I am working cloud commerce edition.

I have upgraded the Magento version from `2.3.5-p2` to `2.4.4`

I have run the upgrade, compile, deploy, indexing and cache commands but the catalog page is going 404 not found.

If I am using the URL like `/catalog/product/view/id/{product_id}` which is working fine.

So how can I regenerate the URL or fix the issue?

Comment: Are you using any third-party SEO extension?

Comment: using Amasty Shopby extension